# Prevent 'range' block from executing over an empty map when Values is not defined

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

I am facing an odd behaviour of helm when using the `range` iterator. My template looks like something like this

```
{{- range .Values.authorizationPolicies -}}
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}-authorization-policy

... 
{{- end -}}
```

When I don't set anything from my values.yaml I see the error below

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: microservice/templates/authorization-policies.yaml:5:11: executing "microservice/templates/authorization-policies.yaml" at <.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}
helm.go:84: [debug] template: microservice/templates/authorization-policies.yaml:5:11: executing "microservice/templates/authorization-policies.yaml" at <.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:154
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:940
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:1068
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:992
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197
```

However, if I define `authorizationPolicies: []`, then the range doesn't iterate.

Seems to me that Helm does not distinguish between a non-existent value and an empty list or map. If the value is not specified in the values file, Helm treats it as an empty map.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is to include the definition of `authorizationPolicies: []` as an empty list in your chart's `values.yaml` file.  Someone installing the chart can still provide a different value using a `helm install -f` alternate values file.

The second-easiest answer is to provide a default empty list when setting up the `range` loop

```
{{ range .Values.authorizationPolicies | default list }}
...
{{ end }}
```

If the value isn't defined anywhere, then `.Values.authorizationPolicies` has a special value of `nil`.  This is different from an empty list or an empty map; it's considered "false" for purposes of conditionals or the `default` function.  In the underlying Go implementation, the best Go type the template engine has to work with is the "anything" type `interface{}` and that's why you see it in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it's still iterate over and empty map when I do what you suggested. What actually did the trick here was doing something like this:

{{- range $value := $.Values.authorizationPolicies | default list -}}
{{- if $value -}}

I dont't like it tho :(

Comment: "Iterate over an empty list" shouldn't emit anything; the body of the `range` loop should execute zero times.

Comment: Agree. But it's actually being executed. I am wondering if this value is coming from somewhere else. I am installing my helm with the command: 

helm install -f example/sampleapp_mesh.yaml --create-namespace -n sampleapp demo ./

Comment: Settings in the `sampleapp_mesh.yaml` will override what's in the chart's `values.yaml`.

Comment: That was actually my bad. The value was coming from values.yaml indeed. Many thanks!